# How to use the new $getField operator in the $project stage in MongoDB 5.0?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoDB now supports key names which contain a period (`.`) or starts with a `$`. (new in version 5.0)

They introduced new operators in the aggregation framework like `$getField` and `$setField` ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/)) to work with these kind of keys but they didn't provide any examples on how to use them in the `$project` stage.

If I have the following collection (from the docs):

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "sweatshirt", "price.usd": 45.99, qty: 300 }
{ "_id" : 2, "item" : "winter coat", "price.usd": 499.99, qty: 200 }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "sun dress", "price.usd": 199.99, qty: 250 }
```

how to project only the `price.usd` field?

Answer (score 2):

That's not right. You can use `$getField` in the `project` stage. However, you'd need to make some additional operations if you want to preserve `price.usd` key

Usage:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "price": {
        $getField: "price.usd"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qg7XHjd5zIs)

Comment: That's right, thank you for your answer. :)
But this way I have to change the key names in the results. Also I want to use these operators in more complex scenarios.
Take this as an example:
`[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "price":  {
           "price.usd": 45.99,
           "price.eur": 48.99
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "price":  {
           "price.usd": 6432.23,
           "price.eur": 6468.32
        }
    }
] `
I want to get or set the `price.usd` field inside the `price` field. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @LorándPéter Well, how about a scenario like that? Imagine that there is a property called `usd` under the` Price` object. While you are getting this data from the database, if you convert the object you received to dot notation, the data you receive can be exactly what you want, such as `price.usd: 6432.23`. So the result will be as you want, but the objects will be in a different format in the database. I can show you that in the answer if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
It would be good, but the problem is I want to store keys which contain dots, and I want to use aggregation framework on this data and get back the same keys. 
Please see the examples:   
[project](https://imgur.com/a/L4DtAtH)  
and 
[set](https://imgur.com/a/5r0uCPG)

Comment: Is there a way to pass a variable to $getField, like `getField: $$variable`, or is that not allow.  I tried doing that, but $getField doesn't seem to allow field ref paths

Answer (score 0):

These new functions can't be used in the `$project` stage as it has very clear structure restrictions:

```
_id: <0 or false>
<field>: <1 or true>
<field>: <expression>
<field>:<0 or false>
```

You can either use `field:0` in the `$project` stage for all other fields:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      item: 0,
      qty: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8vHCMZ803bM)

Or if you have too many fields / an unstructured schema that changes and you can't rely on that you could convert each document to an array using [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), filter that array to contains only the relevant keys then finally convert it back to an object using  [arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      rootAsArray: {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      newRoot: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$rootAsArray",
          as: "field",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$field.k",
              "price.usd"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$newRoot"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gpIRqdmjpkp)

Answer (score 0):

Use $getField operator when you want to get some specific fields from an object that is returned by an expression.

Take as example the following collection: you have a field "items" with an array of objects and a field "selectedItemId" that refers to one of the objects inside the "items" array.

```
[{
    "_id": 111,
    "items": [
      {
        "_id": 211,
        "name": "table",
        "price.usd": 45.99,
        "quantity": 3
      },
      {
        "_id": 212,
        "name": "shoe",
        "price.usd": 45.99,
        "quantity": 3
      },
    ],
    "selectedItemId": 212,
}]
```

Never mind the background of how you got to this collection... You want to check the objects inside "items" and return only the name of the selected item, like that:

```
[{
    "_id": 111,
    "name": "shoe"
}]
```

If you have to do that in the $project stage, you could run a $filter to return the object you want, and wrap everything with the $getField operator to specify you only want the field "name":

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {
        "$getField": {
          field: "name", // return field "name"
          input: { // from the obj returned by the expr below
            $first: { // destruct array to obj as you know you only get one item anyway
              $filter: {
                input: "$items", // filter array "items"
                as: "item", // naming every item as "item"
                cond: { // by
                  $eq: [ // comparing the fields
                    "$selectedItemId",
                    "$$item._id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
])
```

I guess the key is to think it as a projection inside a projection.